# How to get the list of orderers,peers,organizations participated in block chain network?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

What are the commands required to get the above information from the installed block chain network?

Answer (score 1):

Fabric v1.2 introduced a **Service Discovery** that allows applications to query about the Peers, endorsement policies etc.

> The discovery service can respond to the following queries:
>
> - **Configuration query**: Returns the MSPConfig of all organizations in the
>     channel along with the orderer endpoints of the channel.
> - **Peer membership query:** Returns the peers that have joined the channel.
> - **Endorsement query**: Returns an endorsement descriptor for given
>     chaincode(s) in a channel.
> - **Local peer membership query**: Returns the local membership information
>     of the peer that responds to the query.
>     By default the client needs to be an administrator for the peer to
>     respond to this query.

So the command that you are looking for is the `discover` command.

Refer: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/discovery-overview.html

and for Commands: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/discovery-cli.html#

Comment: Thanks for the reply as the above information helped us .But i need some clarification .Do we need to have any configuration file to execute 'discovery 'command ?.when i try to execute 'discover' command ,i got a error like command 'discover ' not found.Can u help me with this ?@Harshit